# Add validation/if else statements to public class functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, class, if-statement, pdo

I'm trying to build a simple blog using PHP PDO but I've got a bit stuck on validation/if else because what used to happen in the no class messy version was it would say "This article does not exist" but now it just shows the page with empty boxes so I was wondering how I add if/else statements to classes to make it work and show the message when the id is not one that matches in the database

```
 public function fetch_data($pid){

    try{
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post where post_id = ? order by post_date desc');
    $query->BindValue(1,$pid);
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetch();

    }
     catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
      }
     }
```

Thats the public function bit of code and the article.php page code is:

```
<?php

include_once('functions/main.php'); 
$post  = new Main;
$check = new Main;
$check_login = $check->logged_in();

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $pid = $_GET['id'];
    $post = $post->fetch_data($pid);

    $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE post SET post_views = post_views + 1 WHERE post_id = ?");
$query->execute(array($pid));
    ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $post['post_title'];?></title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


      <style>
.customimage{
background: url('<?php echo $post['post_image'];?>') !important;
}
</style>


    </head>


<body>

          <div class="pusher">
    <!-- Site content !-->
<div class="ui inverted vertical masthead center aligned segment purple customimage">
 <div class="ui text">
      <h1 class="ui inverted header">
        <?php echo $post['post_title'];?></h1>
              <br>
              <div class="ui black inverted label"> <i class="calendar icon"></i><?php echo $post['post_date'];?></div><div class="ui black inverted label"><i class="user icon"></i> <?php echo $post['post_author'];?></div><div class="ui black inverted label"><i class="unhide icon"></i> <?php echo $post['post_views']?></div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui divider hidden"></div>

<div class="ui container">
<div class="ui segments">
  <div class="ui segment purple">
  <h1 class="ui header">
  <div class="content">
    <?php echo $post['post_title'];?>
     </div>
</h1>
  </div>
    <div class="ui segment">
    <?php echo $post['post_content'];?>
  </div>
  <div class="ui secondary segment">
    <button class="ui labeled icon button">
  <i class="left arrow icon"></i>
  Return to Posts</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
    </body>
</html>

    <?php
}else{
    header('Location:index.php');
}

?>
```

And I can't figure out how to make it so that when you go to ?id=876799 it then says that article doesn't exist but currently its just blank.

Comment: Where is the if / else in question?

Comment: @devlincarnate i've been trying to put them in but i cant see where or how to do it so i asked professionals so i can learn for the future and im very very new to PDO

Comment: Don't construct JSON by hand like that. If you want to echo JSON, use `echo json_encode(array('error' => array('text' => $e->getMessage())));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `$post` after the query and when displaying the results.

```
$post = $post->fetch_data($pid);
if ($post) {
    $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE post SET post_views = post_views + 1 WHERE post_id = ?");
    $query->execute(array($pid));
} else {
    display_post_not_found($pid);
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    ...
</html>
```

In the `display_post_not_found()` function (which you must write) you can display an informative page about the error, or just redirect somewhere.

Full code:

```
<?php

include_once('functions/main.php'); 
$main  = new Main;
$check = new Main;
$check_login = $check->logged_in();

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $pid = $_GET['id'];
    $post = $main->fetch_data($pid);
    if ($post) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE post SET post_views = post_views + 1 WHERE post_id = ?");
        $query->execute(array($pid));
    } else {
        display_post_not_found($pid);
        exit();
    }
    ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $post['post_title'];?></title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


      <style>
.customimage{
background: url('<?php echo $post['post_image'];?>') !important;
}
</style>


    </head>


<body>

          <div class="pusher">
    <!-- Site content !-->
<div class="ui inverted vertical masthead center aligned segment purple customimage">
 <div class="ui text">
      <h1 class="ui inverted header">
        <?php echo $post['post_title'];?></h1>
              <br>
              <div class="ui black inverted label"> <i class="calendar icon"></i><?php echo $post['post_date'];?></div><div class="ui black inverted label"><i class="user icon"></i> <?php echo $post['post_author'];?></div><div class="ui black inverted label"><i class="unhide icon"></i> <?php echo $post['post_views']?></div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui divider hidden"></div>

<div class="ui container">
<div class="ui segments">
  <div class="ui segment purple">
  <h1 class="ui header">
  <div class="content">
    <?php echo $post['post_title'];?>
     </div>
</h1>
  </div>
    <div class="ui segment">
    <?php echo $post['post_content'];?>
  </div>
  <div class="ui secondary segment">
    <button class="ui labeled icon button">
  <i class="left arrow icon"></i>
  Return to Posts</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
    </body>
</html>

    <?php
}else{
    header('Location:index.php');
}

function display_post_not_found($pid) {
    echo "Post $pid could not be found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options:

1. redirect to a page that displays the error, something like `post_not_found.php` or something.
2. wrap the entire html page you have right now with an if/else statement that will output different content based on your criteria.

I suggest you go with the first option, what you need to do is to check if `$post` has data, if it doesn't then you do `header("Location: post_not_found.php");`

Comment: how do i make them work because currently my header redirect only works if its just post.php not post.php?id=857484 and what i want and what it used to do in the really messy 2012 php was it said "Article Not Found" but now if i do post.php?id=857484 it just shows the layout and all but with blank boxes and i want it to show an error message but i dont know how to make that happen with my current code and PDO